# Imagick is recognized by WAMPServer but not by PHP

Tags: installation, wamp, php-extension, imagick

ImageMagick is installed correctly. WAMP'S "PHP Extension" menu also shows php_imagick with a check. phpinfo() shows no trace of the imagick extension except for Apache and System Environment Variables. All paths are correctly specified.

Answer (score 0):

you should check whether in php.ini file there is a line dealing with imagick
extension=imagick.dll

Comment: Yes. I added the line extension=php_imagick.dll, where the dll is placed in the php "ext" subdirectory.

Comment: Did yo urestart the WAMP server after adding the line? is there any error in php or apache log?

Comment: Yes. I was careful to do every basic step (checking path validity and so on). What I didn't do is check the Apache log that says "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20060613\nPHP    compiled with module API=20090626\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />"